# Can someone explain this line of my implementation of React dispatch with useReducer and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

So, to describe it as simple as possible. I have a component App where I'm using the useReducer hook to declare the state and dispatch function, like so:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, initialState)
```

In this component through the JSX I pass the dispatch as argument to functions such as `handleLogin`:

```
function handleLogin(e: React.FormEvent, dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>): void{
    dispatch({type:'login'})
    e.preventDefault()
}
```

Everything works without errors, the only thing is that I don't quite understand what I'm doing by writing this: `dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>`

If someone can explain in detail what this means, would be great. And if it is the best way ?? Which I don't think so, because there is an `any` .. How could it be improved ?

Also, I haven't found documentation to read about these things. Mainly docs about useReducer hook and TypeScript. If someone can help me in this regard I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For the type of the `dispatch` argument you can change the `any` to your action interface/type

`React.Dispatch<ReducerAction>`

Assuming your action is called `ReducerAction`

Hope it helps!